# How does Cauchy's inequality work?

Tags: limits, inequality

I have the following problem:

Prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{|x|^\alpha y^4}{x^2+y^4}$ exists.

I saw elsewhere that by Cauchy's inequality that $x^2+y^4\ge2y^2|x|$.  I'm not sure where this comes from and I can only find the Cauchy-Shwartz inequality online.  I can solve the rest of the problem if I assume this, but why is it true?

Comment: $a^2+b^2-2ab\geq 0$.

Comment: Ah I forgot something so basic, thanks.  Although now that I think about it I can only show that the limit I need is $\le$ the new limit after Cauchy IF it exists, but this doesn't show that it exists, right?

Comment: You can show $x^2+y^4 \ge 2y^2|x|$ by completing the square as mentioned above, AM-GM etc.  To use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, note
$$x^2+y^4=\sqrt{(x^2+y^4)(y^4+x^2)} \ge (|x|y^2+y^2|x|)=2y^2|x|$$

On the question of your limit, I suspect it would depend on what $\alpha$ is... for e.g. for $\alpha = 0$ it does not exist.